# docker stack deploy with docker-compose and publish a port number

Tags: docker-swarm

I just want to have a Nginx container running and publish on port 80

Update: I can see that this has also happened in previous versions:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32111

I am running:

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce
 API version:  1.34
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   1caf76c
 Built:        Mon Nov 20 18:37:39 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   1caf76c
 Built:        Mon Nov 20 18:36:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I am running this on digitalocean and I can see this when `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P`:

```
sshd    1522 root    3u  IPv4  15971      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd    1522 root    4u  IPv6  15973      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
dockerd 5025 root    6u  IPv6  28455      0t0  TCP *:2376 (LISTEN)
dockerd 5025 root   23u  IPv6 227368      0t0  TCP *:2377 (LISTEN)
dockerd 5025 root   29u  IPv6 227378      0t0  TCP *:7946 (LISTEN)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  website:
    image: my/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
```

And then how to starting the service - tried this:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stackdemo
```

But how do you publish the port?

I can see that I can do this from the terminal?

```
docker service create --name my_web \
                        --replicas 3 \
                        --publish target=8080,port=80 \
                        nginx
```

But I can not figure out how from docker-compose, do you know?

Comment: What's not working? Apart from `expose` being unnecessary, you're doing everything right - it should be accessible after your `docker stack deploy`. I tested locally and it works fine. No need to run you `docker service create` command - that would be moot as well

Comment: Ok, intresting - I am running on a virtuel computer on digitalocean. And running the IP address in a browser does not work. I can see that the port is not listening with sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P

Comment: Is your service running? `docker service ls`

Comment: yes: *:80->80/tcp

Comment: And you can't `curl localhost` from the host? What about if you `curl localhost` inside the container?

Comment: Good idea: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: And how about inside the container?

Comment: I don't know how to do that on a service "docker exec services_name ?"

Comment: docker ps will show running containers. Then run docker exec container_id curl localhost on the one you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160975/discussion-between-tj-biddle-and-chris-g).

Comment: I found that it did work if I used only a "clean" nginx. I will use that as a base for my next steps. Thanks a lot for trying.

Comment: Hey Chris - Yeah, there was likely something in your custom image that was causing the container to exit early. I've updated my answer with an explanation if anyone else comes along this - cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our discussion in the comments; it's very likely that your container is failing and restarting - rather than your port isn't exposed.

Your initial compose file is perfect - except the `expose` arguments are actually unnecessary; but Docker will ignore them either way and your service will come online.

So what's happening here is your service was successfully created and now Docker Swarm will keep an eye on your containers - if they fail, it will bring them back online. So checking if you check for running services with `docker service ls` you will see yours online.

Now the tricky part here; is to figure out why your containers are failing. Likely the container will be restarting when you check, so use `docker ps -a` to show all containers, including the stopped ones.

Check for the latest one, and take the "Container ID" and run `docker logs container_id` to find out why your container is failing - solve that, rebuild your image, and update your service to use it - and you should be good to go!

Comment: :-) docker ps is not giving me any running containers - still docker service ls is showing running services. There must be some swarm mapping that I am missing.